# Creating a Form for an Entity that can update other Entity using Symfony Forms

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I have the following entity name EntityUpdater

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\EntityUpdater")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class EntityUpdater
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", options={"unsigned"=true})
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=128)
     */
    private $entityName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", options={"unsigned"=true})
     */
    private $entityId;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=128)
     */
    private $entityColumnName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $entityColumnValue;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", options={"unsigned"=true})
     */
    private $status;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="scheduled_date", type="datetime", nullable=false, options={"default"="CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"})
     */
    private $scheduledDate;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="creation_date", type="datetime", nullable=false, options={"default"="CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"})
     */
    private $creationDate;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="processed_date", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $processedDate;
}
```

I'm using this entity to create scheduled updates to other entities.
For example, if you want to start selling a new product next Monday at 0800, you could create a new Entity Updater, select "Product" as targeted entity through "entityName", select the desired product, its column "status" and set it to the new value.

My problem is how to create an user friendly form for this entity that can update any other entity using Symfony5.
What I mean by "user friendly" is:

- For `entityId`, being able to list with a `<select>` tag all entities, using a different column as label depending on the targeted entity.
- For `entityColumnName`, being able to list with a `<select>` tag, all column for this entity, with a correct label per column.
- For `entityColumnValue`, being able to display the correct form input, based on the Symfony Type class.

Below you have an example of ProductType which "describe" the Product form. I would like my EntityUpdater form to, somehow, have the same column/label/choices when you select the product as the ProductType form.

```php
class ProductType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
            $builder
            ->add('name', TextType::class,  [
                'label'                     => 'Name',
                'required'                  => true
            ])
            ->add('status', ChoiceType::class, [
                'label'                     => 'Product status',
                'mapped'                    => true,
                'required'                  => true,
                'choices'                   => [
                    'Draft'                 => 0,
                    'Discontinued'          => 1,
                    'Out of stock'          => 2,
                    'Online'                => 3,
                ]
            ]);
    }
}
```

Is this achievable ? If so, how ?

Comment: First question : Do you need your `entityColumnName` to be able to select any column of the entity ? Or just a defined list of entity's column ?

Second question : Do you need to be able to select any entity in EntityName or just a selection ?

Comment: @ThibaultHenry It would be best to only select a defined list of entity's column (exclude ID or other sensible columns) and for entity, any entity except maybe myself.

Comment: I suppose you could start with [form events](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/events.html).  They allow you to dynamically modify forms.  But I question your basic approach.  Can't suggest a simple alternative but I can forsee many problems.